# Replacement for YazSoft's Speed Download - Mac

Tags: osx, download-manager

I kept using Speed Download for a long time after its demise, until it broke under El Capitan. The downloader itself still functions, but it can no longer intercept links from Safari.

I've been using [Folx](http://mac.eltima.com/download-manager.html) recently, but its most irritating feature is that it insists on coming to the front when a link is sent to it & presents a dialog to confirm before the download will actually take place.
Its second most irritating feature is that for no apparent reason it periodically relaunches itself if quit & bounces in the Dock. When I go to see what it wants... it wants nothing.

I've also tried [Downie](http://software.charliemonroe.net/downie.php) - but that's not really what I'm looking for. YouTube download capability is low on my requirements list.

Of the capabilities of Speed Download, what I need is

- Multi-stream/segmented downloads. This is my prime concern; segmenting & DLing 12 simultaneous streams is empirically the best way to max my bandwidth.
- Intercept from Safari
- HTTPS/SSL-capable, including passwords for specific sites
- No insistence on being frontmost to commence download

Less important

- Timer function, preferably set & forget, so I can set downloads for overnight
- Resume capability.